# Is it possible to change name of resources of API in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am new to AWS API Gateways. I created an api named : `test-api1`. Also, I created a resource named `test-resource1`. Now I want to change the name of this resource. I couldn't find any option to rename resources.
Is this possible or do I need to create new resource?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this depends on how you deploy your API. If you use an OpenAPI spec, then you can rename your resource there. If you used a CloudFormation template (or a AWS CDK stack) then you can rename your resource there.
If you merely clicked-together your API in the AWS Management Console (Web UI), then there isn't a way in that Web UI to change the resource's name.

You have to revert to using the AWS CLI for that.

There is the `apigateway update-resource` AWS CLI command to update the name of an API Gateway API resource.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-resource.html
(search for "**To rename a resource (pathPart) in an API**"):

```
aws apigateway update-resource --rest-api-id <api-id> --resource-id <resource-id> --patch-operations op=replace,path=/pathPart,value=<new-name>
```